# Remove Pattern Lock

Tags: lock-screens

I am unable to remove the pattern lock on my Moto G 2 because the none option is greyed out and a message saying 'Disabled by administrator, encryption policy or credential storage'.  I have already tried having all accessibility settings off as suggested by other members here. Please help.

Comment: do you use a VPN by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the pop-up message... Go to Settings - Security - Device Administrators and revoke the Device Administration privileges for everything except Android Device Manager and then change or remove the pattern lock. Note that if you have a corporate email setup, they may require this, so to remove the device administration privilege you may have to completely remove the account.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there's an app that is mandating the pattern.  For example, I know that when you have a corporate MS Exchange account set up that account can mandate a pattern.  If you don't have any exchange email, I guess it could be another app, but that's the one type that I know will do it.  It's possible the new Android Pay will mandate a pin/pattern as well, but not sure if that's the case...